# Applying dplyr filter operation to specific rows without losing other data

Tags: r, dplyr

Apologies if this has been asked before. I couldn't find any satisfactory answers, although it sounds like it should be a rather straightforward operation.

I have my data

```
  transition_frame                     name state_number lifetime
             <int>                     <chr>        <dbl>    <dbl>
1               38 //Traces_exp1_tif_pair10            1       NA
2               44 //Traces_exp1_tif_pair10            2        6
3              352 //Traces_exp1_tif_pair10            3      308
4              362 //Traces_exp1_tif_pair10            4       10
5              379 //Traces_exp1_tif_pair10            5       17
6              388 //Traces_exp1_tif_pair10            6        9
```

It was easy enough to calculate the rowwise differences between transition frames, but since there's no "transition" between state 0 and 1, it breaks the flow.

How can I make only the first row be `transition_frame - 1` (hint, it's 37), without touching any other data?

Imagine,

```
group_by(name) %>%
filter(state_number == 1) %>%
mutate(lifetime = transition_frame - 1) %>%
unfilter() # To retrieve dropped data
```

Which would result in a whole set, with the first row computed, and NOT *only* the first row.

```
  transition_frame                     name state_number lifetime
             <int>                     <chr>        <dbl>    <dbl>
1               38 //Traces_exp1_tif_pair10            1       37
2               44 //Traces_exp1_tif_pair10            2        6
3              352 //Traces_exp1_tif_pair10            3      308
4              362 //Traces_exp1_tif_pair10            4       10
5              379 //Traces_exp1_tif_pair10            5       17
6              388 //Traces_exp1_tif_pair10            6        9
```

Comment: I don't really understand your questions, but perhaps you are looking for `coalesce`.

Comment: Added some more code. Does that explain it better?

Comment: please add your expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the following work for you?

```
df <- data.frame(transition_frame = c(38, 44, 352, 362, 379, 388),
                 name = rep("//Traces_exp1_tif_pair10", 6),
                 state_number = seq(1, 6))

df %>% mutate(lifetime = diff(c(1, transition_frame)))

  transition_frame                     name state_number lifetime
1               38 //Traces_exp1_tif_pair10            1       37
2               44 //Traces_exp1_tif_pair10            2        6
3              352 //Traces_exp1_tif_pair10            3      308
4              362 //Traces_exp1_tif_pair10            4       10
5              379 //Traces_exp1_tif_pair10            5       17
6              388 //Traces_exp1_tif_pair10            6        9
```

Replace 1 in `diff()` with other values if you want the transition frame in state 0 to take on different values.

Answer (score 1):

Hope an approach similar to below code might help you!

```
df <- data.frame(transition_frame=c(38,44,352),
                name=c('//Traces_exp1_tif_pair10','//Traces_exp1_tif_pair10','//Traces_exp1_tif_pair10'),
                state_number=c(1,2,3),
                lifetime=c(NA,6,308))
df[df$state_number==1 & is.na(df$lifetime),"lifetime"] <- 
  df[df$state_number==1 & is.na(df$lifetime),"transition_frame"] - 1
df
```

Comment: Not too elegant, but it works. Thanks! I'll still keep an eye out for the dplyr version though :)